# CakePHP 2.1 hasAndBleongsToMany or hasMany through?

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many-through

I'm new to the hasAndBelongsToMany relationships in CakePHP.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the following scenario.  Do I use hasAndBelongsToMany or hasMany through?

In my application I am creating Repair Orders.  The Repair Orders have Op Codes, which are assigned to employees.  There can be more than one Op Code per Repair Order.  So, it's likely I'll have something similar to the following:

RepairOrder1 - OpCode1 completed by Employee1, OpCode2 completed by Employee2

From what I read in the manual, the reason you can't use HABTM relationships for this type of situation is that when saving the data, the original information is removed first.  However, in 2.1 there is a 'unique' key that you can set to have it keep the existing information first.  So do I create a HABTM or a  hasMany through?

**EDIT**

Here's my schema:

```
/* repair_orders */
CREATE TABLE repair_orders (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number VARCHAR(16),  //Auto-generated repair order number 
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);

/* Employees */
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(16), 
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);

/* op_codes */
CREATE TABLE op_codes (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(16),
    sale_material DECIMAL(10,2),
    cost_material DECIMAL(10,2), 
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I am trying to assign more than one op code to the repair orders, and also keep track of which employee did that specific op code.  So I can have a repair order with 3 op codes, each with a different employee.  So I think that requires another table, something like:

```
/* repair_order_assignments */
CREATE TABLE repair_order_assignments (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    repair_order_id INT(16),
    op_code_id INT(16),
    employee_id INT(16)
);
```

So my associations would be:

```
Repair_Order_Assignment hasMany Employee, Op_Code
Employee belongsTo Repair_Order_Assignment
Op_Code belongsTo Repair_Order_Assignment

Repair_Order_Assignment hasAndBelongsToMany Repair_Order
Repair_Order hasAndBelongsToMany Repair_Order_Assignment
```

Then according to the manual, when hasAndBelongsToMany associations are saved, the association is deleted first. You would lose the extra data in the columns as it is not replaced in the new insert.  However, it goes on to note that in 2.1 there is a unique variable that can be set to save the extra data.  Will this setup work with the unique key or should I use a hasMany through approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you'd use neither in this case:

```
OpCode belongsTo RepairOrder
OpCode belongsTo Employee
RepairOrder hasMany OpCode
Employee hasMany OpCode
```

When retrieving your data, use [CakePHP's Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

```
$this->RepairOrder->find('all',
    'contain' => array(
        'OpCode' => array(
            'Employee'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear in my description.  The op codes are a separate item.  They have a name and some prices. I'll edit my post to give more information.

Comment: I don't believe I would change my answer - I still don't see a need for another table, nor another association.  What don't you think works with this setup?

Comment: if I change the price for an op code, I don't want to have to change it on every entry in the op code table

Comment: So... just change one then.  Changing one doesn't require that you change them all.

Comment: I have an op code OCX, which has a labor cost of $12.  I want to assign that to a repair order and an employee.  Next repair order comes along, OCX again, and it gets a repair order and employee.  Next one comes along and it's ATI, with it's own price.  It gets a repair order and employee.  Now when I want to change the price of OCX op codes, I would have to look through entire op code table and change each one.  Correct?  Or am I missing something?  Did you see my schema in my edit?

Comment: You're making it more complicated than it needs to be and confusing the heck out of me in the meantime.  You're talking about labor costs...etc, yet you have not a single field that references "labor". I highly recommend just going back through and re-writing your question.

Comment: I did basically re-write my question in my edit.  In my schema I left out many fields for brevity's sake.  Labor just happened to be one of them.  Exchange labor for material cost.  Either way, if you read my whole edit I think you'll get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  The op codes are items with set prices.  There should be no foreign keys in that table, as it's just a list of my op codes and their respective prices.

Comment: I started a new thread on the topic trying to better explain my question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351784/cakephp-hasandbelongstomany-vs-hasmany-through